# Are these two expressions in C equal?

Tags: c, operators, equality

Is  `a*=b;`  the same as  `a*a=b;`, and if not, what is its equal?

I'm little confused because I keep getting wrong answer on this test:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    main () 
    {   
        int i, j, a=1, b=3; 
        for(j=1; j<3; j++)  
          a*=b;
        b++;
        printf("a=%d", a);
    }
```

Comment: This is an elementary-grade syntax/operator question. What does your favorite C book say about it?

Comment: did you think what `a*a = b` is and how b is assigned to a variable called `a*a`?

Comment: Nikola: if an answer solved your problem best, then please click on the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

`a *= b;` is equivalent to `a = a * b;`.

`*=` is a compound assignment operator - you can read more about them here: http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/opers.html#assign

There's also a good explanation of this and other operators here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_operator_types.htm

Answer (score 1):

What is the "wrong" answer you're getting, and which one do you expect? Note that `b++` is *outside* of the loop; use `{` and `}` to create a block for the loop's body if you want it executed within the loop

```
for(j=1; j<3; j++) {
    a*=b;
    b++;
}
```

Other than that, to answer your actual question: [What Eoin said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101507/is-this-expression-correct-in-c-correct-equal#31101531), and in this context take a look at what an [lvalue and rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) is.

Answer (score 0):

`a*=b` is equivalent to `a = a*b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a *= b;
```

compiles.

```
a * a = b;
```

does not compile, giving something like this:

```
 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

From the above we can conclude:

No, the both expressions are not equal

---

As the second expression above does not compile you either have no equivalent or endlessly.

For the first expression there are (at least) two equivalents:

```
a = a * b;
```

or

```
a = b * a
```

Answer (score 0):

First) You need to in-close the for loop with {}

```
int j;
for(j=1; j<3; j++){
    printf("like this");
}
```

Second) a*=b is the same as a=a*b. a*a=b is trying to store the value of b in a variable called a*a.

```
int a*a;
int b;
a*a=b;
```

Which won't work because a*a isn't a valid variable name.

Lastly) The result of your code, how you have it written (once you fix the for loop with {}) should be:

```
a=3a=12
```